# How to write this code as a pure function?

Tags: pure-function

The code has three places with same variable `ls`. So I think it would be possible to write it as a pure function.

```
ls = {{1, a}, {2, b}, {3, c}};
MapThread[Insert, {ls, Table[0, {Length[ls]}], Table[2, {Length[ls]}]}]
```

My attempt is:

```
MapThread[Insert, {#, Table[0, {Length[#]}], Table[2, {Length[#]}]} & ls]
```

which is not correct.

Comment: This gives some answer:
    MapThread[Insert, {#, Table[0, {Length[#]}], Table[2, {Length[#]}]}] &[ls]

Comment: @Andrew can you explain why this works? why put operator there

Comment: `& @ls` instead of `& ls` would also work. Writing `& ls` is like writing `f ls`, which in *Mathematica* syntax means `f multiplied by ls` - and you can't multiply an anonymous function with a list.

Comment: @Pickett What about `Length@(#&ls)`, does this contradict with what you are saying?

Comment: Any reason you don't just use `Riffle[#, 0] & /@ ls`?

Comment: @buzhidao take a look at what `# & ls` returns and why `Length` is "correct". I'voting to close this question as a duplicate of common pitfals. But you may also by interested in `Function` `Pure Function` entries in documentation.

Comment: @ciao This is powerful, I never noticed it.

Comment: @buzhidao If you interpret me literally I guess; you can multiply an anonymous function by a list, but it doesn't make sense to do so. What you end up with is a list of values multiplied by anonymous functions, but what good is that. Use `Column @@ FullForm[# & ls]` to see what I mean, those expressions that you generate by multiplying `ls` with `# &` don't mean anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
f = Thread@Riffle[Transpose@#, 0, 2] & ;
```

or ciao's solution

```
f = Map[Riffle[#, 0] &]
```

gives

```
f[ls]
```

> {{1, 0, a}, {2, 0, b}, {3, 0, c}}

Comment: `Replace[#, {x_, y_} :> {x, 0, y}, 2] &[ls]`

Comment: @garej another very good solution.